# На каком этапе загрузки системы определяются переменные окружения?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, posix

Скрипт запускается по `crontab` с параметрами:

*/usr/spool/cron/crontab/root*

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

Наблюдается интересная особеность, не все переменные окружения присуствуют, одна из главных это `$USER` - пустая, приходится ее определять в ручную:

*script*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
export USER=$(id -un)
...
```

Так же отсутствуют некоторые пути в `$PATH` для этого подгружаю недостающее:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source /etc/profile
...
```

На какой стадии загрузки доступны переменные окружения в полном объеме?
Стоит ли ждать N секунд прежде, чем стартовать скрипт запускаемый по `cron`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вопрос о «влиянии этапов загрузки на переменные окружения» абсолютно лишён смысла. ведь:

- любой процесс может получить от родительского процесса какой-то набор переменных окружения («родитель» может, конечно, и не передавать ничего — смотря что программист, его писавший, придумал) и может передать его (модифицировав) «потомку»;
- любой процесс может модифицировать свой набор переменных окружения: добавить, удалить переменные, изменить их значения — всё в руках автора-программиста.
- с процессом загрузки операционной системы всё это никак не «пересекается», разве лишь в том смысле, что эта самая «загрузка» есть рекурсивное порождение огромной кучи процессов.

---

по поводу переменной окружения `USER`. [подробно](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76354/110559). вкратце:

- стандарт *posix* [не требует](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) её наличия, но требует наличия переменной `LOGNAME`.
- в переменные окружения процессов пользователя они попадают (наследованием от «родителя» к «потомку») как правило от программы `/bin/login` (или её аналога типа `xsession` и т.п.).
- программа *cron* не устанавливает эту переменную для дочерних процессов. и исходя из вышеизложенного действует вполне корректно. можете взять значение из переменной `LOGNAME`, чтобы не запускать дополнительный процесс, как вы написали в вопросе.

---

по поводу переменной окружения `PATH`.

минимально-дефолтное значение для неё программа *cron* задаёт самостоятельно. но часто
мэйнтейнеры переопределяют её в глобальном конфигурационном файле программы *cron* (вывод может отличаться в вашей системе):

```
$ grep PATH /etc/crontab
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

если есть необходимость — можете переопределить её таким же образом **в своём** пользовательском файле *crontab* (редактирование которого запускается командой `$ crontab -e`). (заодно можете там определять и переменную `USER`. только учтите, что подстановок переменных в файлах *crontab* не осуществляется. надо указывать явно: `USER=vasja`)

Comment: Отлично, у нас был спор на работе по поводу `USER` т.к. все рабочие скрипты зависят от нее. Отдельное спасибо за ссылку на POSIX.