# $USER внутри docker

Tags: docker

Захожу внутрь докер-контейнера:

```
docker exec -it da6d0899c833 bash
```

Делаю

```
echo $USER
```

И мне говорят, что тут пусто. Почему так?

Comment: очевидно же: потому что этой переменной окружения не присвоено значение. к самой программе docker это не имеет вообще никакого отношения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907170/178576

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables